# Export functions together with tables from a postgres schema

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a postgres schema which I would like to export a few tables from. To do this, I obviously used the `--table` flag in the `pg_dump` command. This works fine except for the part where I need to restore the dump into a postgres server and I start getting errors due to a missing `function`. I am trying to add the missing `function` to the `pg_dump` command as well but I'm not sure how.

Here is what I thought should work;

```
pg_dump --dbname=foo --file=foo.dump --host=localhost --username=postgres --schema-only --table=bar --table=foo_function
```

This command runs successfully without any errors but on restore, `foo_function` still goes missing. I have tried looking for ways to specify function export in `pg_dump` but I couldn't find anything. How do I go about this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify individual functions in a `pg_dump`. I see two ways forward:

1. Use the `--exclude-table` option to exclude all the tables you don't want in the dump. Then the dump will contain all functions, operators, data types and other objects you created.

   [You can use regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS):

   > Advanced users can use regular-expression notations such as character classes, for example `[0-9]` to match any digit. All regular expression special characters work as specified in [Section 9.7.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), except for `.` which is taken as a separator as mentioned above, `*` which is translated to the regular-expression notation `.*`, `?` which is translated to `.`, and `$` which is matched literally. You can emulate these pattern characters at need by writing `?` for `.`, `(R+|)` for `R*`, or `(R|)` for `R?`. `$` is not needed as a regular-expression character since the pattern must match the whole name, unlike the usual interpretation of regular expressions (in other words, `$` is automatically appended to your pattern). Write `*` at the beginning and/or end if you don't wish the pattern to be anchored. Note that within double quotes, all regular expression special characters lose their special meanings and are matched literally. Also, the regular expression special characters are matched literally in operator name patterns (i.e., the argument of `\do`).
2. Create a custom or directory format dump (`--format=c` or `--format=d`). Then you can extract individual elements with `pg_restore`:

   - create a "table of contents" file with

     ```bash
     pg_restore --list --file=toc dumpfile
     ```
   - edit `toc` and remove all the objects you don't want to restore
   - restore with

     ```bash
     pg_restore --use-list=toc --dbname=targetdb dumpfile
     ```

Comment: This is not manually triggered sorry. This is part of an automated pipeline which probably rules out no 2. Because of this as well, it will really be a high level work getting list of all tables I would want to exclude as I am working with a large schema. I was just hoping for an easier way out

Comment: `--exclude-table` allows patterns; perhaps you can use that to make it a little easier.

Comment: Is there some kind of way I could match tables that fail some pattern? something like negating a pattern; I could use such to inverse the `--exclude-table` values

Comment: I later went with option 1 with a bit of work as well. I first of all got a list of all tables in the schema and computed the `exclude-table` list in a way that it excludes all tables except the ones I initially wanted to specify with the `--table` flag. This way, the dump only contains the tables I need as well as the fuctions and other non tabular objects as well. Thanks for the tip.